# pyspark List subfolder of a folder in s3 bucket

Tags: dataframe, amazon-s3, pyspark, s3-bucket

I have a `s3` bucket in which i store datafiles that are to be processed by my pyspark code.
the folder i want to access is:

```
s3a://bucket_name/data/
```

this folder contains folder. my aim is to access the content of last added folder in this directory.
I didnot want to use boto for some reasons.
is there any way to access the folder list so i can pick the folder that i suppose to access.
I can access files if i specify the folder but i want to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using s3fs, which is a filesystem-style wrapper on boto3. The docs are here: http://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Here's the part you care about (you may have to pass in or otherwise configure your AWS credentials):

```
import s3fs
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=True)
fs.ls('my-bucket')
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great.  If you're running this on an EMR cluster, add `pip install s3fs` to your bash bootstrapping script,  and you'll probably use `s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)` in your code or EMR notebook.